# BASH find ctime not working as expected

Tags: bash

I can't get "find" to locate old files. I am chaining my finds into one statement and all other segments are working fine. Here is a trimmed down version of what I have. It searches the directory tree of $path and creates separate temp files containing only new line characters for each item found: all files, files changed greater than 365 days ago, and all directories. The files and directories are working fine (as well as 6 other chained searches I didn't include here), but the ctime is returning 0 hits and I know there are matching files in the directory I am using.

```
find $path \
\( -type f -fprintf /tmp/files.txt "\n" \) , \
\( -type f -ctime +365 -fprintf /tmp/oldfiles.txt "\n" \) , \
\( -type d -fprintf /tmp/dirs.txt "\n" \)
```

This seems to be in line with the man page for find. It says that -ctime n finds files with a change time of n days. The + gives >n days, the - gives <n days, and no sign gives exactly n days. Despite the appearance that everything is in line, my temp file is still coming out with 0 lines. Any thoughts? Also of note, to conserve processing time I need to find these files while traversing the file system in one pass.

Comment: How old are the files you are trying to match? Since `-ctime` has to round for fractional days, your expression matches files that were created at least 36*6* days ago.

Comment: There are definitely files in my directory which are much older than 365 days.

Comment: Are you sure that these files haven't been touched at all in 365 days? What does `ls -lc` say about the files you want to match?

Comment: Turns out the owner of the directory went off and changed the permissions to everything in the directory tree recently. While mtime is usually less reliable as a "creation date" than ctime, I will have to use mtime for the purposes of this tool. Thank you to everyone who contributed.

Comment: Most Unix/Linux filesystems don't store a file's creation time.  For one that did, there would be effort involved in making Linux aware of them (systems calls, where to store the extra data to start with, etc).

Answer (score 5):

"Change time" means "metadata change time", i.e. when the permissions or ownership has changed. Consider using mtime instead.

Comment: Everything I have read on the subject indicates that ctime is usually closer to the creation date since metadata is changed less frequently than the file contents.

Answer (score 2):

-ctime n
              File's status was last changed n*24 hours ago.  See the comments
              for -atime to understand how rounding affects the interpretation
              of file status change times.

-mtime n
              File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago.  See the  comments
              for -atime to understand how rounding affects the interpretation
              of file modification times.

Status = permissions, user, group, possibly ACLs, etc.

Content = your file data

If your files had their ownership changed 1.5 years ago and aren't showing up, that's a problem, but if it's the change in their content you're trying to detect, try -mtime.

Sidenote:  -atime can be tricky to use in some systems, since it constitutes an access as well.
Sidenote2: This is a *find* question, and isn't at all specific to bash.